# CSS Image Slider - Can't go to the next image

Tags: css

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot the following codes?

The elements are positioned correctly but the arrows do not change the image. Only Image 1 is shown and it seems to be stuck there.

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
<span id="target-item-1"></span>
<span id="target-item-2"></span>
<span id="target-item-3"></span>

<!-- Start carousel items-->
<div class="carousel-item item-1">
<a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-3"></a>
<a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-2"></a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item item-2">
<a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-1"></a>
<a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-3"></a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item item-3">
<a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#target-item-2"></a>
<a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#target-item-1"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS (leaving only the crucial parts)

```
.carousel-wrapper .carousel-item {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 25px 50px;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-wrapper [id^="target-item"] {
display: none;
}

.carousel-wrapper *:target ~ .item-1 {
opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-wrapper #target-item-1:target ~ .item-1 {
opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-wrapper #target-item-2:target ~ .item-2, .carousel-wrapper #target-item-3:target ~ .item-3 {
z-index: 3;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Do advise if there is a better way to implement a responsive image slider (with arrows) that does not require javascript. Been searching for hours for a lightweight solution that is easy to implement.

Comment: Could you please reduce the example to a a few lines that demonstrate what the issue is? That will likely help your own ability to debug it.

Comment: Not a coder but with my limited knowledge of CSS, reduced the above codes to only reflect the transition. Do advise if you can identify the error. Thanks!